# Display glutDisplayFunc function in loop

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I want to call the glutDisplayFunc function again in loop but it's error. How to solve this problem?

```
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("simple");
    for (int m = 0; m <= l; m++) {
        cout << "Please enter a stage: ";
        cin >> num;
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
    }
    initializeGL();
    glutMainLoop();
```

Comment: Which error? What are you trying to do? Calling `glutDisplayFunc` in a loop sounds rather useless to me.

Comment: The OpenGL window didn't show anything as it could be. For the reason that I want to call that function because I want to select the stage to show the graph until the loop is run out of.

Comment: As already written in the answer, `glutDisplayFunc` doesn't draw. Beside this, if you block the process that also handles window messages by waiting on commandline input, your window won't work anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glutDisplayFunc` does not call the function you pass to it itself. It basically stores which function should be called inside the `glutMainLoop()`.

In the glut main-loop the rendering function is then called whenever necessary. If you want it to redraw as fast as possible, call `glutPostRedisplay();` at the end of the display function.